# why dojo build does not wok?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo

environment:win7 ,nodejs 0.10.24,dojo 1.9.2

cmd:

E:\download\dojo-release-1.9.2-src\dojo-release-1.9.2-src\util\buildscripts>node ../../dojo/dojo.js load=build --release --profile .\profiles\base.profile.js

result:

processing profile resource E:/download/dojo-release-1.9.2-src/util/buildscripts
/profiles/base.profile.js

info(107) Package Version: package: dojo; version: 1.9.2

processing profile resource E:/download/dojo-release-1.9.2-src/dojo/dojo.profile
.js

discovering resources...
starting reading resources...
starting processing raw resource content...
starting tokenizing resource...
starting processing resource tokens...
starting parsing resource...
{ [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)

Where  can I download full example that does work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Java, or you need to not use ShrinkSafe nor Closure Compiler as your optimizer.